# Set file attributes in Bash

Tags: git-bash

In bash I want to set file permissions.

I'm trying this:

```
find ./GMDS_SRC/* -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

But only the last argument (*.c) is used.

Why is that? And more important. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ./GMDS_SRC/* \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' \) -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

**( expression )**: True if expression is true.
`expression -o expression`: Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.*

parenthesis are prefixed by a backslash () to prevent evaluation by the shell.

Comment: Perfect. So obvious and simple. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you can upvote and accept my answer.